# Whether to implement task or stream based approach

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-task

I have a data pipeline process which runs for 12 hours. It's polling for files in a directory and gets triggered every 15 minutes. Based on some business logic it's either going to publish message to a messaging queue or does some database insert/update. I have come up with 2 approaches:

1. I run it as task but in that case how can I publish message without getting my code tightly coupled to any specific message queue provider?
2. I run it as stream but in that case it will have to run 24/7, although the process doesn't need to run anymore than 12 hours.

What it the best way to architect this process in SCDF?

Answer (score 0):

You can have your `Spring Cloud Task` application producing task events into a messaging system. This can be done by adding a dependency `spring-cloud-task-stream` in your app. For more information on this, you can refer the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-cloud-dataflow-task-events) here.

With respect to your question on whether to run a stream or batch is entirely up to you based on various factors including the platform on which you run this and the cost etc.,

Here are some of the options:

- SCDF supports scheduling of tasks in Kubernetes and CloudFoundry. If you are on one of these environments, then you can **schedule** a `task` to check for the incoming files and have the task to complete
  (1) publishing of the messages to the configured messaging system (via the `spring-cloud-task-stream` mentioned above)
  (2) jdbc insert/update (you would need to have this defined in your batch)
- If you can't do manual undeploy/re-deploy of the stream, You can use SCDF REST client to trigger stream `deploy/undeploy` via a custom task application. This way you can control when to have your streams running.